Error generating chart too many pixels using sentinel 1
I am generating a plot but I have an error for generating a chart, my script is like below:
var cor = [[105.81352993964532, -5.657379634654876],
          [105.81352993964532, -6.012584749422468],
          [106.18706509589532, -6.012584749422468],
          [106.18706509589532, -5.657379634654876]
          ]

var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(cor)
Map.centerObject(roi);

var sen1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
.select('VV')
.filterDate('2020','2021')
.filterBounds(roi)
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10, 10, 'month'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(4, 4, 'day_of_month'))
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW')).mosaic()

//print(sen1.aggregate_array('orbitProperties_pass'))

Map.addLayer(sen1.clip(roi),[],'sen1',false)

print(
  ui.Chart.image.histogram(sen1,roi,10)
  )

var despeckel = sen1.focalMean(100, 'square', 'meters');

Map.addLayer(despeckel.clip(roi),[],'sen_despeckel',false);

print(
  ui.Chart.image.histogram(despeckel,roi,30)
  )
  
var thr = despeckel.lt(-22);

Map.addLayer(thr.clip(roi),[],'oil_spill',false);
  
  
var mask = thr.updateMask(thr);

Map.addLayer(mask.clip(roi),[],'mask',false)

var area = mask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6));

var oil_spill_area = ee.Number(area.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry: roi, scale: 100
  }).values().get(0));
  
print(oil_spill_area)

var oil_spill_vector  = mask.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: roi, scale: 100
  });
  
Map.addLayer(oil_spill_vector)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: oil_spill_vector, description: 'oil_spill', fileFormat: 'SHP', folder: 'oil_spill2'
  })

Error generating chart: Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 16441942, but maxPixels allows only 10000000. Ensure that you are not aggregating at a higher resolution than you intended; that is a frequent cause of this error. If not, then you may set the 'maxPixels' argument to a limit suitable for your computation; set 'bestEffort' to true to aggregate at whatever scale results in 'maxPixels' total pixels; or both.
